# Origin of the phrase "That is how it is"

Tags: etymology, phrases, popular-refrains

Where does this come from?

> That is how it is.

Comment: Maybe. But we would like to know more if we are to help.

Comment: @ethel I've edited the question to make it a little clearer. If I've misinterpreted it, please re-edit to put it right.

Comment: The earliest instance I find of this phrase *tout simple* is in the testimony of 'Cockerell, *labourer*' in the 1834 [*Report*](http://books.google.com/books?id=LnBbAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA48&dq=%22that+is+how+it+is%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=YK2fUIriEMr1qAGcxoDoBA&ved=0CEsQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the Poor Law Commissioners. I don't think it "comes from" anywhere but the language itself. That is how we say it.

Answer (score 2):

I’m tempted to agree with StoneyB’s comment that that’s just how it is: language works that way. The repetition serves to emphasise the finality of the statement.

There is an early example of similar repetition in the Bible’s Gospel of John (John 19:22), which was originally written in Greek and translated into Latin before English:

> ὃ γέγραφα, γέγραφα
>   Quod scripsi, scripsi.
>   What I have written, I have written.

It certainly has a finality in English that is presumably present in the other languages too (I haven’t studied Biblical Greek). Consequently the structure is ancient and common to many languages, not just English; and it can easily be applied to simple constructions such as “It (or *that*) is how it is”.

Comment: You can take it back another Testament: *´ehyeh ´asher ´ehyeh*, I am what I am (Exo 3:14). It is what it is.